# Batch file recursively find files and rar them

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Parent Directory which hosts many sub directories, and in every sub directory there is .mpg movies. Some of the directories might contain one or more .mpg movies.

I would like to automate the process below, which I have been doing manually.

### Step One

If the directory has more than 1 .mpg file, I create separates directories for each and move each file into its directory, naming the directory as per the name of the file.

### Step Two

I rar each video file in its directory as per one of my profiles, by that it splits the movie into 50MB parts, test the archive, delete the source, and instructs winrar to wait if another rar is executing. I am doing this so I can queue jobs manually.

### Step Three

After having all the rars in the sub directories, I start creating a checksum for every directory, therefore leaving checksum.sfv in every directory.

### Step Four

I copy the parent folder and its sub directories to my external drives.

I was hoping that someone could assist me in creating a script. I was able to automate the process of creating directories as per the name of the file, and moving the file. However, I never succeeded in automating Step two.

I am using the below software

- Winrar from rarlabs
- exf from exactfile

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Try asking a single, specific question.

Answer (score 3):

This is supposed to be a question and not a description of task for someone to do instead of you. Try to define a problem and edit your post to show obstacles. This will find more support here in this case.

Comment: Yes, it's surely a comment, but my rep. is less than 50. So I cant leave them for now.

Comment: Have another up vote for doing your best to help someone else out without flaming them. You should be able to leave comments now...

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Get Windows Powershell

**Step 2**

Write a script, to do what you need. If you get stuck, ask a specific question